# Using HTMX on a web form, how do I grey out the button while a request is processed or the form fields are not filled?

Tags: htmx

I'm trying to learn HTMX https://htmx.org/ by building a simple example.

This here is a form with two data entry fields.

It should fire, when the "search" button is clicked or enter is pressed.

This works.

I would like to provide some feedback to the form user:

1. to grey out the "search" button so it's only activated when there's data in both fields
2. to grey out the "search" button while a request to the backend it curently in progress. Alternatively show a spinner and block input while the request runs.

   ```
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>example</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.7.0"
                integrity="sha384-EzBXYPt0/T6gxNp0nuPtLkmRpmDBbjg6WmCUZRLXBBwYYmwAUxzlSGej0ARHX0Bo"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!!!</h1>

    <div id="main">
        <button hx-get="/button1" hx-target="#main">
            Get stuff
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="main2">
        <form>
            <label for="search">label:</label>
            <input id="s1" name="q" type="search" placeholder="one">
            <input id="s2" name="q2" type="search" placeholder="two">
            <button hx-post="/button2" hx-target="#main" hx-trigger="click, keyup[enterKey] from:body">
                Search
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This should be easily done by using htmx extensions.

Check these out:

https://htmx.org/extensions/disable-element/

https://htmx.org/extensions/loading-states/